# Can not get canvas from DOM on window resize and binding canvas with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

In my viewmodel constructor I do this:

$(window).resize(resizeCanvas);

```
function resizeCanvas() {

    var canvas = $('#mycanvas');
    canvas.attr('width', 333); //max width
    canvas.attr('height', 444); //max height

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

}
```

All the canvas or context related methods are missing instead I get a canvas html element, why this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#mycanvas")` returns a jQuery object that *refers* to your canvas DOM element.  It does not actually return the canvas element itself.  Use the jQuery object like an array to get the actual canvas object:

```
canvas.length === 1; // jQuery object refers to only a single element
var canvasElement = canvas[0]; // get actual canvas element
var context = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
```

It is a good idea to adopt a naming convention for your variables to know when they are jQuery objects or DOM elements.  I like to prefix `$` for my jQuery variables:

```
var $canvas = $("#mycanvas");
$canvas.attr(...);
var canvas = $canvas[0];
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `var canvas` is actually a jQuery object, not the actual html canvas element.

Try this instead:

```
var canvas = $('#mycanvas')[0];
canvas.width=333; //max width
canvas.height=444; //max height

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```